# Adjust number of samples in Tensorflow nce_loss while training

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, loss-function

I'd like to adjust the sampling rate during training of my neural network to test some stuff and see what happens. To achieve that my idea was to create an new loss and optimizer for every iteration using the same computation graph.

```
def optimize(self, negative_sampling_rate):
    return tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(self.learning_rate).minimize(self.calc_loss(negative_sampling_rate))

def calc_loss(self, negative_sampling_rate):
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.nce_loss(
        weights=self.graph.prediction_weights,
        biases=self.graph.prediction_bias,
        labels=self.graph.labels,
        inputs=self.graph.hidden,
        num_sampled=negative_sampling_rate,
        num_classes=self.graph.prediction_weights.shape[1])
    )

def train(self, batch_inputs, batch_labels, negative_sampling_rate):
    feed_dict = {self.graph.X: batch_inputs, self.graph.labels: batch_labels}
    _, loss_val = self.session.run(
        [self.optimize(negative_sampling_rate), self.calc_loss(negative_sampling_rate)], feed_dict=feed_dict
    )
    return loss_val
```

But I'm a little bit worried about the optimizer. I've heard that *optimizers have internal variables*, which *change* on every *training iteration*. Is that true for all optimizers or only or a some, and if so which ones are usable for this approach?

The Neural network should then be trained like:

```
for step in range(training_steps):
    NN.train(inputs, labels, compute_sampling_rate(step))
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it should be okay to change the number of samples in the nce loss without causing problems for the optimizer. The internal variables stored by some optimizers relate to the historical gradients of the trainable variables in your graph.

Secondly, if you do want to reset the state of your optimizer for some reason, the way I do it is by putting the optimizer in a variable scope. Whenever I want to reset it then I run the `reset_optimizer` op.

```
reset_optimizer = tf.no_op()
with tf.variable_scope('optimizer'):
  train_op = optimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)
opt_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, "optimizer")
if len(opt_vars):  # check if optimzer state needs resetting                                                                                          
  reset_optimizer = variables_initializer(opt_vars))
```

Comment: Ooh..... the optimizer is an object with a minimization function. I have not seen that I can initialize the optimizer without calling its minimization function directly.... I think it's time to take a break. 

Thank you very much, your comment was helpful.